# Can either Power Apps or Power Automate be used to refresh Power BI dashboards that get their data from the 'Import' option?

Tags: powerbi, dashboard, powerapps, power-automate

My business doesn't like using Direct Query. They believe in putting all data in to Power BI via the 'Import' option. This means that whenever our team wants to refresh the data in a Power Bi dashboard, they must:

1. Download the .pbix file from the SharePoint where they're published.
2. Open that file in Power BI desktop.
3. Click to refresh the data from our SQL server.
4. Re-publish the dashboard.

This has to be done for every single dashboard that we have. This is plainly absurd.

Can either Power Apps or Power Automate be used to refresh several dashboards at once? I don't know what licensing I have for Power Apps, but when I went through the list of connections that the web version let me use, I saw no options for Power BI. As for Power Automate, I saw no way to access my dashboards.

Comment: The normal procedure is to enable "Scheduled Refresh". https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/refresh-scheduled-refresh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your data is hosted in your internal network, you need to install the Data Gateway on a machine in your network. You can then use that data gateway for scheduled refresh and don't need to download/refres/upload the pbix file.

The Data Gateway is a free download. You can find links to that in the menus of the Power BI online interface.